# Screen freezes and the app quit

Tags: java, android, sql

I'm trying to send some info to my mysql db after clicking on a button but my screen freezes and then it quit.
Here is the code:

```
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            try
            {
                new SendInfo(email.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString());
            }catch(Exception e){
                error.setText((CharSequence) e);
            }

        }
    });
```

and here is the SendInfo class:

```
public SendInfo(String email, String pass) throws Exception
{
    Connection conn = null;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://ip...:3306/"; // info changed
    String dbName = "db"; //info changed
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "user"; //info changed
    String password = "pass"; //info changed
    String table = "users";

    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
    DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(100);
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);

    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
    java.util.Date utilDate = cal.getTime();
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new Date(utilDate.getTime());

    st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO users VALUES('1','Komal','asd',"+sqlDate+")");
    conn.close();

}
```

I didn't even used the values I get as parameters to make it easier but it's still not working.

Comment: What does your LogCat say?

Comment: Do you get the "Application not responding" dialog? It looks like you are trying to perform network actions on the main thread...

Comment: Looks like you're performing a blocking operation on the UI thread. That's playing with fire. The UI thread is the third rail, touch it and Android may decide to fry your app on the spot.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the following line made the error:

```
error.setText((CharSequence) e);
```

Changing it into

```
error.setText(e.toString());
```

fixed it.